# Async update axes in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have multiple `highcharts` and I need to update all of the x-axes to a common new value from a numeric input.

In my real example, this operation is rather slow. I was wondering if I can somehow implement an async function here?

I tried to reproduce my issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/fmattioni/vcn9bxyo/2/

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @FMM, Maybe disabling the update animation and using `setExtremes` method will be enough? Please test this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/62a3sLc7/

Comment: That indeed does the trick! That is fantastic! Feel free to post this as an answer and I will gladly accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the update animation and using `setExtremes` method will be enough:

```
function updateAxes() {
  var newX = document.getElementById("update_axes").value;

  Highcharts.charts.forEach(chart => {
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(null, newX, true, false);
  });
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/62a3sLc7/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes